# Setting unicode id3 tag from command line (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, id3

How do I pass unicode in an argument to a command?

I want to reset all of my Björk music to have the same name (different rips/downloads have slightly different names) so I plan on doing the following:

```
$> id3v2 -a Bjork  Bjork/*.mp3
```

I'd like to get the umlaut in there (UTF-8: 0xC3 0xB6 (c3b6), UTF-16: 0x00F6) but don't know how to input the unicode in this (type of) command.

Presumably I could use the same approach to correct the directory name too.

Answer (score 1):

There are often strange keyboard contortions that I can never remember.  Best option I find is simply to copy and paste it from another source.  One possible source would be your favourite word-processor and "insert symbol" or such like.  You obviously found the letter (as you have it pasted in the question).  A simple copy and paste should be enough.  The command line will usually cope with unicode "these days" (and I'm concious I'm answering a six-year-old question!)  Add quotes to be safe...

Comment: An aswered late is better than a never aswered because it may help some new users having the same issue.